# React: Set up a large number of routes and have GET request render correctly on web server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, design-patterns, redux, react-router

## Introduction

Let me just start by saying that this is a very difficult problem for me and I've been coding professionally for 5 years.

### Use Case

[Zillow](http://www.zillow.com) has implemented this design pattern successfully. If you type something into the search box and hit enter, it takes you to a search result page. If you click on one of the results, the URL at the top changes and a modal pops up with information about the home you just selected but the page does not refresh (probably React.js).

Important: *If I copy the URL and paste it in a new browser, the listing shows up along with the other results for whatever I searched for*

#### Thoughts...

Now, consider this for a moment: There are millions of listings on Zillow.
[Let's just use this one as an example.](https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Old-Town-ME/84999468_zpid/6306_rid/45.005107,-68.629017,44.895403,-68.813553_rect/12_zm/)

The URL is pretty long. It looks like this: https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Old-Town-ME/84999468_zpid/6306_rid/45.005107,-68.629017,44.895403,-68.813553_rect/12_zm/

Those folders are pretty deeply nested.

#### Questions:

Are there actually just *billions* of folders on the server?
One for each ID of every type of item they track on top of one folder per each position on the map?

### Actual Case

I have a React web app that I'm working on and for a while, I couldn't get the application to load when a request was made to the server for a specific route. At the present moment, you can actually find a development version staged on the internet [here](https://www.signaturerep.com/).

*Note that my temporary solution (you will read about this below) has not yet been implemented in the staging environment yet*

When you search for something, it takes you to the search results page, but if you refresh you get a 404 from the server. The server thinks you're either looking for a folder titled "search" or just some arbitrary file with the same name.

#### So, this is what I did and it works "in theory."

I made a folder named "search" inside the root directory, copied the application and pasted it into that folder, made it so that the URL reads "/search/" when the users submits a search (looks like: `this.props.history.push('/search/')`), and then made a few modifications to the App to make it so that the search value is stored in `localStorage`. Now, in theory, when you make a request to https://www.signaturerep.com/search you get the copy of the application that gets the search value from `localStorage`.

*Now, I realize that this is probably just horribly wrong. Let us continue.*

So, now I'm faced with this problem where if I want to do separate URLs for each listing (I have 20,000 listings) and I want the app to load correctly when a user copies the URL from the top of the browser, I would have to make one copy of the app and place it in a unique folder for each listing.

#### Questions:

Am I right?
What am I doing wrong?
How can I make it better?
Is there such a thing as a node.js web hosting server?
Is there a way to tell the server it's a React route and not a request to a folder?

## UPDATE:

I can see how it was hard to understand the Original Post. Gavin's answer provides a really good guide and his build does work. The problem I had was with my web server. I was just building an app with Wepback and dropping it into a PHP server. Here is the JavaScript I used to fix the problem:

### Server.js

```
// Simply install 'node' and 'express' globally and drop this file in your /dist folder
var express = require("express");
// var router = express.Router(); // You may need this in the future
var path = require("path");
var app = express();

const PORT = 80;

// console.log("A request was made to server.js");
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
app.use("/search", express.static(__dirname));
app.use("/search/:value", express.static(__dirname));
app.use("/search/:value/:id", express.static(__dirname));
app.use("/messages", express.static(__dirname));
app.use("/favorites", express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Started listening on port", PORT);
});
```

Just  drop this file into your `/dist` folder, and run it on a web server with NodeJS installed (not the whole story, you need to SSH into the server and run it with `node server.js`), such as a Digital Ocean droplet. Your web server must have NodeJS installed globally.

I also found that you can get route props with a spread operator like so:

```
      <Route path="/search/:value/:id" // this one needs to go before /search/:value
        render={(routeProps) => <Search {...routeProps} 
          OtherProps={this.state.OtherProps} />
        } />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So even with this awesome write up for a question I'm unsure what you're asking. I think this may be what your referencing? I use React, and this is what we do...

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={NewHome} />
    <Route path="/work" component={MyWork} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    <Route exact path="/blog" component={Blog} />
    <Route path="/blog/:slug" component={SingleBlogCard} />
    {/* <Route path="/work/:slug" component={Client} /> */}
    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

Notice

```
    <Route path="/blog/:slug" component={SingleBlogCard} />
```

Here I am saying when a link to /blog/'anyslugname" occurs render the singleBlogCard. Or modal in your zillow example. I am filtering my data to only show the blog with the matching slugname in the params. With this method worst case scenario is O(N). You'd have to touch every data set if it was the last one.

Then where I am .map, forEach, for looping the data set...

```
<Link to={`/blog/${this.props.blog.url}`}>
```

Notice I would then need to have some reference to the slug, or ID in your use case somewhere on the data object.

UPDATE FOR OP.
These are the only 'routes' you can ever share with a link that will be live. 
If you want to have other routes like specific houses. You have to add them here. To demonstrate this make a simple test component and have it render to /test. Otherwise any URL changes you see is just react simulating them, based on user clicks, it's not actually loading any different HTML.

```
<div id="root-container">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route component={App} />
        <Route path="/search/:slug" component={singleHouseSearched} />
        <Route exact patch='/test component={test} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using React Native? I'm using React for the web. If you are using React for the web, when a regular get request is made to /blog/'anyslugname', does it render correctly with the card for that slug? The problem that I'm having is that when I copy the URL and paste it (making a normal request) to /blog/'anyslugname', I'm getting a 404.

Comment: In my case it would be /homes/:listing_id

Comment: I am familiar with RESTful routing but I'm just not sure how to get it to render correctly when a regular request is made to that URL from a browser.

Comment: Heres a live example from the code i posted above https://gthomas.me/blog/reactdatavisualization

Comment: can you share your github repo so I can get a global perspective?

Comment: It's completely pulled apart at the moment and I never actually used Redux but here is it: https://github.com/internationalhouseofdonald/srep-1.1.1

Comment: It should still run out of the box. It just needs to be reconfigured to run on a web server. I have the output of the dev-server going to my Wamp64 server. You can find that in the webpack.dev.config file.

Comment: what comp is the data fetch?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. I use whatwg-fetch and a PHP file handles the backend.

Comment: My database is a MySQL database.

Comment: What web hosting service do you use? Could it be possible that your web hosting server is set up to handle React Routes and mine isn't? I'm using Dreamhost...

Comment: I'm still reading, I used firebase. I think what you need to do is setup a link on your modal ( <Link to={`/houses/${this.props.houses.id}`}>
). 

Setup this route     <Route path="/houses/:slug" component={singleHousePage} />

Then <singleHousePage/> componentDidMount(){Make fetch to your database with the 'params' or 'slug' or 'id' for you to pull that specific house

Comment: Do you have your blog page saved as a GitHub repository by any chance? I would love to see the code for this. I don't actually have the "RESTful" routing set up on the listing modals yet but the main problem is that when I make a raw request to it, I'm getting a 404 from the server. Try going here: https://www.spyro.world/search Nothing.

Comment: The /search is being simulated by react router dom, it's not actually doing anything until you setup a ROUTE in your browser router to show specific things. https://github.com/internationalhouseofdonald/srep-1.1.1/blob/master/src/index.js so in this you would add     <Route path="/search/:id" component={singleHousePage} />

Comment: But I'm not getting anything. Like, it's not even finding the App at the root directory. I do actually have the routes set up in a switch.

Comment: Thank you. Give me a day to look at your code and see what I'm doing wrong. You've been very helpful.

Comment: Check my updates. Basically, super high level, you need to have your modal be a <Link to="search/'houseid'> Then your singleHouseCard, on Mount can do an api call with this.props.params (which will be your id) to fetch all the house data.

Comment: OH heavens i also forgot!!! This does not work in development. Meaning if on localhost, you copy the link with the blog url, then paste it, it will throw 404!

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is with my server. It wasn't running NodeJS. I have a VPS up and running with Dreamhost and I just "turned on" NodeJS for my website. I have a page of instructions that I have to follow but I inadvertently dropped a chair on my foot this morning and, thus, will have to come back after I regain feeling in my foot.

Comment: After a long haul I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I was trying to run my React app on a PHP server! So, I looked at the repository you gave me and I noticed that I couldn't find a server.js or anywhere for that matter where you had spun a server. So I assume that AWS provides a NodeJS server out-of-the-box.

Comment: either that or you must have a server configured somewhere.

Comment: Tried to spin up my own server. Realized I may need Express... :D

Comment: I'm giving you the answer for this because I had no clue what I was doing when I asked the original question. I can try to rephrase the question but it would make your answer only an introduction into getting Express to serve up my app statically on a NodeJS server with `app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));`